# Connect-ServiceFabricCluster is not recognized on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I have a three node service fabric cluster on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. I wanted to connect this cluster from node0 using powershell script from this node. I installed

- Powershell
- Latest ServiceFabric Module using following command Install-Module -Name Az.ServiceFabric -RequiredVersion 3.0.2

Then I tried to use "Connect-ServiceFabricCluster" command with parameters to connect cluster but I receive following error "The term 'Connect-ServiceFabricCluster' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

The same command works fine in Service fabric deployed on windows cluster.
Am I missing any module in Ubuntu VM ?

Comment: Did you also run `Import-Module Az.ServiceFabric` and are you running inside the `pwsh` shell?

Comment: yes. I had already run the command inside pwsh but that did not help.

Comment: Can you run `echo $PSVersionTable` to see which `pwsh` version you have installed?

Comment: PSVersion is 7.2.3

Comment: I think you could be running into [this](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/1343) issue.